# Adding a responsive sidebar to a Leaflet application in R

Tags: r, leaflet, responsive, sidebar

I am building a Leaflet application in R. I want polygons in my map to be clickable. A side bar should then show additional information about the clicked element.

The only solution I could find are in Javascript, such as this one: 
https://github.com/turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/

I only use R and don't know how/if I can combine that with Javascript